# How can I pass an array with grape swagger ui?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger, swagger-ui

I have definition of api endpoint below:

```
params do
  requires :ids, type: Array, desc: 'Array of group ids'
end
```

I can't pass an array form the UI generated by Swagger. If I enter `[1, 2, 3, 4]` or `ids%5b%5d=1&ids%5b%5d=2&ids%5b%5d=3` then both become invalid. If I call the api from spec with an array it works. My client would like to try the whole api from Swagger, so I would like a solution which works with Swagger UI.

Comment: I got the same problem ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify what Boti was saying, I think he meant that he changed the type for the array param to string, and sent a string of a JSON array - meaning `"[1,2,3]"`. This isn't ideal, obviously, but it would work if you parsed it on the API side. So the params would be -

```
params do 
  requires :ids, type: String, desc: 'Array of group ids'
end
```

To be clear, this is an issue with Swagger UI working with grape-swagger, especially since Grape Swagger only supports Swagger 1.2. Grape Swagger has an issue sending the correct format for an Array to Swagger (see [this Github Issue](https://github.com/tim-vandecasteele/grape-swagger/issues/237)).  Grape will handle the Array type just fine, you just won't be able to test it in Swagger-UI.

For our project, we just didn't use Swagger for this parameter. I'd rather have the testing platform (Swagger-UI) not work correctly than to edit otherwise correct code in the actual product.

Answer (score 1):

my solution for all cases:

```
params do
  requires :ids, type: Array[Integer], desc: 'Array of group ids', 
           coerce_with: -> { |val| (val.is_a?(Array) ? val : val.to_s.split(',').map(&:strip)).map(&:to_i) }
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I did it with String type params

```
params do
  requires :array, type: String
end

post 'test_array' do
  params[:array] = params[:array].split(',')
end
```

then in Swagger UI, I can pass a string to mimic array like so.

`item1. item2. item3` instead of `[item1. item2. item3]`

this might not be a good approach, but can be a alternative.

Answer (score -3):

Finally I passed a JSON array as String.

Comment: can you please expand on your answer/solution and give an example of what and how you did it